# SED command to the following

Tags: sed

Using SED I would like to transform several hundred lines in a text file from:

Input example:

```
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/3
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/436
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/9167
```

into

Output:

```
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/3/pdf/3.pdf
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/436/pdf/436.pdf
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/9167/pdf/9167.pdf
```

I was wondering what SED command I would use to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: You should include all info within the question itself, *especially* if the site you're linking to does not exist :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: `sed 's|[0-9]\+$|&/pdf/&.pdf|g'`

Comment: IT LOOKS LIKE MY PREVIOUS COMMENTS AS WAY OF THANK YOU HAVE BEEN DELETED. REALLY APPRECIATE THE HELP EVERYBODY!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Run:** `echo "https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/3" |\ 
sed "s|\(https:\/\/mysite.demo.com\/topics\/en-gb\)\/\([0-9]\+\)|\1/\2/pdf/\2.pdf|g"`

**Output**:
`https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/3/pdf/3.pdf`

Here I use `sed "s|||"` instead of `sed "s///"`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample input and expected output, this `sed` command would work:

`sed -E 's,(.*\/)([0-9]+$),\1\2\/pdf\/\2\.pdf,g' text_file`

Output:

```
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/3/pdf/3.pdf
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/436/pdf/436.pdf
https://mysite.demo.com/topics/en-gb/9167/pdf/9167.pdf
```